# Dimmer rotation span wider than the light intensity span

Tags: lighting, dimmer-switch

I had a guy install a dimmer for my kitchen's spotlight. It works as supposed to except for one small detail. The spots are totally off not at the end of the rotation of the controller but at about 40%.

If the full turn is 360 degrees giving max light, they become uneluminated at about 140 degrees. In reality, I'd like them to be slightly on even at 0 degrees. Turning off is done by pushing the button.

I could try to fix it myself or together with the electrician. However, I need advise on what to tell him. I know jack about electricity so I'm not even sure if anything could be done about it to begin with. I just find it counter-intuitive to have rotation span left to go at the end of the illumination decrement.

Comment: What make and model is the dimmer?

Comment: Are you willing to go low-voltage PWM, or alternately, upspend into commercial tier lighting e.g. 0-10v?  You're asking a lot of triac dimming.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Not sure. The electrician installed it. originally he put in a switch that I had to hold pressed in order to dim up or down. How do I check the info you require?

Comment: @Harper What is triac dimming? I'm not sure how to respond to the othe rstuff. They got me 8 spots, 5W each. The dimmer is said to hold for 50 Watt. Please advise.

Comment: @KonradViltersten if you can turn the power off, take the dimmer out of its backbox without disconnecting the wiring, and post photos of the labeling on it, that'd help us identify it

Comment: Are your lights incandescent or halogen or CFL or LED?

Comment: @JeffCates LED. As far I've been told. It's apparently the "way to go" today in Sweden, as far I've heard. Not sure if it's true but we Swedes are very prone to jump on the latest trend in everything we do (which sometimes is wise but hardly always, hehe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LED's are not capable of a full 360 turn on the dimmer switch. LED's require a minimum voltage to pass thru to light them up. Your dimmer allows a much lower voltage thru than the LED driver can convert. One way to test this, is to put a regular incandescent bulb in the socket(s) and try your dimmer switch. I am not aware of any LED bulbs yet, that can dim so low that they barely shine.

Comment: That seems to align with my observations. The question is if it's possible to do something about it. E.g. physically force the dimmer to stop turning after x degrees, before in hits the minimum value. Like a radial offset of minimum...